# Iterate over multiple vectors, perform operation after n elements

Tags: c++, c++11, vector, iterator

I have several `std::vector`s and I need to iterate over them, one after the other, so that I can perform a custom operation considering the first set of N elements, then the second set of N elements, and so on until the last element of the last vector.

One possible way to do it would be to copy each vector into a single larger vector (example with 2 input vectors):

```
void foo(const vector<int>::iterator& it, const vector<int>::iterator& it2)
{
}

void iterate(const vector<int>& a, const vector<int>& b, int n)
{
    vector<int> c = a;
    c.insert(c.end(), b.begin(), b.end());

    int i, j, len = c.size();

    for (i = 0, j = 0; i < len; i++)
    {
        if (i > 0 && i % n == 0)
        {
            // custom operation from c.begin() + j to c.begin() + i
            foo(c.begin() + j, c.begin() + i);
            j = i;
        }
    }

    if (i % n != 0)
    {
        // custom operation from c.begin() + j to c.end()
        foo(c.begin() + j, c.end());
    }
}



vector<int> a(100), b(50);
iterate(a, b, 32);
```

But this approach would require an additional vector allocation, possibly huge. Is there a way to perform the same operation, as fast as possible, without the need of the additional vector?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With [range-v3](https://github.com/ericniebler/range-v3), it is simply:

```
void iterate(const std::vector<int>& a, const std::vector<int>& b, int n)
{
    auto r = ranges::view::concat(a, b) | ranges::view::chunk(n);
    for (const auto& e : r | ranges::view::bounded) {
        foo(e);
    }
}
```

[Demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/0b73d612bb877049)

With for-range available with c++17.

Comment: Very interesting, I wonder what would be the performance loss by using this library.

Comment: @Nick: There is proposal to have this lib in standard. the view is light-weight: there is no copies of vector, so it should be performant.

Answer (score 2):

you can use an array of vectors instead of declaring separate vectors and simply iterate over them.

```
vector<int> v[n];
vector<int>::iterator it;

for(i = 0; i < n; i++) {
   for(it = v[i].begin(); it < v[i].end(); it++) {
      // operation
   }
}
```

Comment: But this would imply to modify the original data structure which is something I can not do.

Comment: so you can use an array of vector references and initialise it with references to vectors in your original data structure

Answer (score 2):

Why not write your own iterator?

An iterator (provided you can limit yourself to a subset of all possible iterator operations) is simply a class where you provide the operations you need.  In your case, you only have to implement ++, == and *.

You can write this iterator class like this:

- Start by writing a class called `VirtualCollection`.
- Add a member to `VirtualCollection` that is a vector with pointers to the underlying data structure you want to loop over (in your case also vectors).  All underlying data structures must have the same type (so not looping over a `vector`, then a `list`, ...).  Let's call this underlying data structure `V` for the rest of this answer.  Let's call this member `m_collections`.
- Add a method `addCollection` where you pass a reference to `V`.  Push_back a pointer to `V` in `m_collections`
- Add an inner class with the name `iterator`.

  - Add two members of type `V::iterator` (or `V::const_iterator`).  Call one `m_begin` and one `m_end` (or use your own preferred naming style).
  - Add a member of type `V::iterator`, called `m_current`.
- Add a begin to `VirtualCollection`, which returns an instance of the `iterator` inner class.  `m_begin` and `m_end` should be initialized to the begin and end of the first vector in `m_collections`.  `m_current` should be initialized to `m_begin` as well.
- Implement the * operator of the `iterator`.  It should simply return the contents of `m_current`.
- Implement the ++ operator of the `iterator` by passing itself to a method `VirtualCollection::increment`.  This increment method will increment `m_current`.  If `m_current` is m_end, all 3 members will be reinitialized with begin and end of the next collection in `VirtualCollection`.
- Then add some logic to correctly handle the end of the loop and the boundary cases (collection empty, ...).  I leave this as an exercise ;-)

Comment: While I like this fundamental approach, the problem is that writing iterators is not a simple or quick task. Maybe it's why Boost has a helper library for this: [Boost.Iterator](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/release/libs/iterator/doc/index.html)

Comment: @Andy, I agree, but in many cases it's enough to write begin, end, ++, == and * methods.  And while this doesn't make it a complete iterator, I think it's enough for the most common uses.  If I can call begin and end, increment the result, compare it and take the contents, it's enough for me to call it an iterator, even if it doesn't make it a complete one.

Answer (score 0):

You can construct a temporary vector pointing to the input vectors, and operate with them in a loop

```
// not tested
void iterate(const vector<int>& a, const vector<int>& b, int n)
{
    vector<const vector<int> *> c;
    c.push_back(&a);
    c.push_back(&b);

    for(auto vec : c)
    {
        //operate on (*vec), which are a and b
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot mix iterators from two different containers. Therefore, when you jump from the first container to the second, this won't work.

If your primary concern is the the allocation of an additional vector, you can work in place and only allocate a temporary vector when going from the first to the second vector. This will reduce the additional memory requirements to `n`.

```
void iterate(const std::vector<int> &a, const std::vector<int> &b, int n)
{
    int remain = a.size();
    for (int i = 0; remain >= n; remain -= n, i += n) {
        foo(a.begin() + i, a.begin() + i + n);
    }

    if (remain > 0) {
        std::vector<int> tmp;
        tmp.insert(tmp.end(), a.end() - remain, a.end());
        tmp.insert(tmp.end(), b.begin(), b.begin() + n - remain);
        foo(tmp.begin(), tmp.end());
    }

    int start = n - remain;
    remain = b.size() - start;
    for (int i = start; remain >= n; remain -= n, i += n) {
        foo(b.begin() + i, b.begin() + i + n);
    }

    if (remain > 0)
        foo(b.end() - remain, b.end());
}
```

---

If you don't care about doing exactly `n` elements every time, you might also just process one vector and its rest, and then process the next vector

```
void iterate(const std::vector<int> &v, int n)
{
    int remain = v.size();
    for (int i = 0; remain >= n; remain -= n, i += n)
        foo(v.begin() + i, v.begin() + i + n);

    if (remain > 0)
        foo(v.end() - remain, v.end());
}

std::vector<int> a(100), b(50);
iterate(a, 32);
iterate(b, 32);
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use std::reference_wrapper like this:

```
static int val = 1;
void foo(const vector<int>::iterator& it, const vector<int>::iterator& it2)
{
    std::for_each(it, it2, [](int& v) {v = val; });
    val++;
}

void iterate(const vector<std::reference_wrapper<vector<int>>>& data, vector<int>::size_type n)
{
    vector<int>::size_type tmp_beg = 0;
    vector<int>::size_type tmp_end = n;
    for (std::reference_wrapper<vector<int>> vref : data)
    {
        vector<int>& v = vref.get();
        while (tmp_end < v.size())
        {
            foo(v.begin() + tmp_beg, v.begin() + tmp_end);
            tmp_beg = tmp_end;
            if (tmp_beg >= v.size()) {
                tmp_beg -= v.size();
            }
            tmp_end = tmp_beg + n;
        } //tmp_end >= v.size()

        foo(v.begin() + tmp_beg, v.end());

        val--; //We need the same value again....

        tmp_beg = 0;
        tmp_end -= v.size();
        if (tmp_end == 0) {
            tmp_end = n;
        }
    }
}


int main()
{
    vector<int> a(100), b(50);
    iterate({ a,b }, 32);
    return 0;
}
```